# Create custom DELETE method with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm having a problem to do a delete request with a body. I'm using Retrofit 1.9 with OkHttp 2.2.

So i found a solution [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/330) and others giving the same solution, which is to create a custom delete method like this :

```
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@RestMethod(hasBody = true, value = "DELETE")
public @interface CustomDelete {
    String value();
}
```

I added this code in my API interface (with all the methods to request my API).

But Android Studio cannot resolve the symbol METHOD and RUNTIME. I don't know what to include to be able to use it.

If someone can help me to figure out, with an explanation would be great.
Meanwhile i keep looking on internet to find a solution (and then to share here).

Comment: Did my answer help? Please mark it as the correct answer if it did so that it helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Target & @Retention are declared in the Android SDK, under java.lang.annotation

```
public @interface Target {
    /**
     * Returns an array of the kinds of elements an annotation type
     * can be applied to.
     * @return an array of the kinds of elements an annotation type
     * can be applied to
     */
    ElementType[] value();
}


public @interface Retention {
    /**
     * Returns the retention policy.
     * @return the retention policy
     */
    RetentionPolicy value();
}
```

From the source, @Target accepts ElementTypes and @Retention accepts a RetentionPolicy.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html

Try this instead

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !